# add calculated column to pandasdataframe depending on NULL values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe like this
[image]

I need to add two columns:

```
df['paidInDays'] = df['sdDatePaidCancelled'].sub(df['sdBillDate'], axis=0) / np.timedelta64(1,'D')
df['toBePaidInDays'] = df['sdDueDate'].sub(df['sdBillDate'], axis=0) / np.timedelta64(1,'D')
```

However some rows have sdDatePaidCancelled NULL and I cant neither convert it to datetime neither make the calculation.

Any tips to get through this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need convert values to datetimes, then `NULL` are converted to `NaT` and you can subtract values:

```
cols = ['sdDatePaidCancelled','sdBillDate','sdDueDate']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_datetime)
#if possible some non datetimeslike values 
#df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce')
```

Comment: I get this error : ParserError: Unknown string format: NULL

Comment: @LuisValencia - So use commented solution `df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce')`